# Get elements of an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I am getting a list of objects like this:

```
IEnumerable personeller = (IEnumerable)sicil_model.OlayForm_Personel();
```

I am looping inside it like this

```
foreach (var personel in personeller)
{
 //can't do anything...
}
```

I am looping inside `personeller` and I can see all elements like this

```
personeller[0] | { Id = 5, Kimlik = "Koray Durudoğan", EMail = "koray@outlook.com", DepartmanAdi = "Yazilim", PozisyonAdi = "Yazilim Geliştirme" }

personeller[1] | { Id = 6, Kimlik = "Hasan Pınar", EMail = "hasan@dincerelektronik.com.tr", DepartmanAdi = "Yazilim", PozisyonAdi = "Yazilim Geliştirme" }
    .
    .
    .
```

And goes like this.. The thing is, I can't access elements of objects. For example, how can I get Id of personeller[0] or Kimlik of personeller[1] ?

I made a class like this

```
public class Personel_Form 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Kimlik { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public string DepartmanAdi { get; set; }
    public string PozisyonAdi { get; set; }
}
```

but I couldn't manage to convert 'personel' to this class, inside my foreach loop.

Lastly, Here is the method which turns the list:

```
public object OlayForm_Personel() 
    {
        return (from p in Entity.GetEntity().Sicil
                           select new 
                           {
                            Id = p.Id,
                            Kimlik = p.Isim + " " + p.Soyad,
                            EMail = p.EMail,
                            DepartmanAdi = p.Departman.DepartmanAdi,
                            PozisyonAdi = p.Pozisyon1.PozisyonAdi
                           }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: what is the return type of OlayForm_Personel?

Comment: You can access a IEnumerable index by using `ElementAt()`

Comment: What is the original returntype of `OlayForm_Personel`? Depending on what you actually get you could use `.Cast<Personal_Form>()` or simply `.ToList()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your sentence of *I am looping inside personeller and I can see all elements like this* and the given sample data I deduce that the collection returned by the function stores items of the `Personel_Form` type.

Two options:

1. You are casting it into the non genetic `IEnumerable` that holds the
   items as `object`s. you can cast it to the correct type:

   ```
   IEnumerable personeller = (IEnumerable)sicil_model.OlayForm_Personel();

   foreach (var personel in personeller)
   {
       var personalForm = (Personel_Form)personel;
       // personalForm.Kimlik
   }
   ```
2. **But a better approach is**: instead of using the non generic `IEnumerable` use the generic `IEnumerable<T>`:

   ```
   IEnumerable<Personel_Form> personeller = sicil_model.OlayForm_Personel();
   ```

---

As for your latest errors (from comments) it is because your function returns an anonymous type and not the `Personel_Form` type. Instead if instantiating an anonymous object instantiate a `Personel_Form`:

```
public IEnumerable<Personel_Form> OlayForm_Personel() 
{
    return (from p in Entity.GetEntity().Sicil
           select new Personel_Form
           {
            Id = p.Id,
            Kimlik = p.Isim + " " + p.Soyad,
            EMail = p.EMail,
            DepartmanAdi = p.Departman.DepartmanAdi,
            PozisyonAdi = p.Pozisyon1.PozisyonAdi
           }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: You can't cast the result of `OlayFrom_Personal` without knowing what it actually returns. Edit: oh, sorry that was the other answer, yours must have popped up almost at the same time.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer - from the sample data in the question it is clear that each item is of the type of `Personal_Form`

Comment: I thought you had the cast to `(IEnumerable<Personel_Form>)` too - my mistake

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer - That's fine :) I'm just happy that you didn't just downvote and left but stayed to check the issue - it is a rare thing to come by in SO :)

Comment: var personalForm = (personel)personel; gives error like The type or namespace 'personel' could not be found, so I tried var personalForm = (Personel_Form)personel; but it gives an error like ''<>f__AnonymousType1`5[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]' '..

Comment: Please show implementation of `sicil_model.OlayForm_Personel()`. It probably has a linq `.select` that return a `new {..}` instead of `new Personel_Form {...}`

Comment: @KorayDurudogan - you are welcome :) updated answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If its possible, you could change your method from

```
public object OlayForm_Personel() 
    {
        return (from p in Entity.GetEntity().Sicil
                           select new 
                           {
                            Id = p.Id,
                            Kimlik = p.Isim + " " + p.Soyad,
                            EMail = p.EMail,
                            DepartmanAdi = p.Departman.DepartmanAdi,
                            PozisyonAdi = p.Pozisyon1.PozisyonAdi
                           }).ToList();
    }
```

to

```
public IEnumerable<Personel_Form> OlayForm_Personel() 
    {
        return (from p in Entity.GetEntity().Sicil
                           select new Personel_Form
                           {
                            Id = p.Id,
                            Kimlik = p.Isim + " " + p.Soyad,
                            EMail = p.EMail,
                            DepartmanAdi = p.Departman.DepartmanAdi,
                            PozisyonAdi = p.Pozisyon1.PozisyonAdi
                           }).ToList();
    }
```

then you could change your consuming code to this

```
var personeller = sicil_model.OlayForm_Personel();

foreach (var personel in personeller)
{
    // personel.Kimlik
}
```